# Is there a quick way to convert a non Maven project to a Maven project within Netbeans?

Tags: java, maven, netbeans, java-11

With a recent upgrade to Netbeans, I am now using JDK 11 however this has caused issues with a web application that I maintain. Many solutions point to adding dependencies to a POM.xml file however I dont have this file as part of my application as Ive never used Maven.

Therefore is there an easy way for me to convert this web application to a Maven one within Netbeans to allow me to begin using dependencies?

Comment: This link can help: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XaumVyY4vYM

Comment: (1) `File` -> `Project`-> Categories : Java With Maven -> Projects: Web Application.
(2) `File` -> `Project`-> Categories : Java With Ant -> Java Web -> Projects: Web Application
(3) compare difference between config with Ant Project and config with Maven project.

Comment: Thank you. Im currently having problems getting the Maven project to run so had to raise another question. Once this is sorted then I can look to migrate the older project into the Maven project.